# Mongo Error: Duplicate Key error makes no sense

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hi fellow developers! 
I've got this error showing up in my console when I try to save two identical documents in a collection in MongoDB that has nothing to do with the index shown in the error.

**Here's the error:** E11000 duplicate key error collection: Bohemian.orders index: user.email_1 dup key: { user.email: null }

Now this makes no sense, because I'm trying to save an Order document in a separate collection, which has nothing to do with the user router I had set up previously.

**Here is the schema and model code:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    amountToPay: Number,
});

const Order = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);

module.exports.Order = Order;
```

As shown here, I am only trying to save the amount to be payed into the database in a separate collection.

**Here is the router file:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { Order } = require('../models/Order');

router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const orders = await Order.find();
        if (orders.length === 0) return res.status(404).send("There are currently no orders");
        res.send(orders);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        next();
    }
});

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const order = new Order({
            amountToPay: req.body.amountToPay
        });
        await order.save();
        res.send(order);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.error(ex);
        next();
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see there is nothing relative to the error that I'm getting and I have no clue why I'm getting a duplicate user.email = null key , when I haven't made any reference to the User model or router.

**Here is the POST call I'm making from POSTMAN to test:** [image]

Pretty straight forward, nothing extreme, nothing tangled, right? Well the first ever POST call saves the document in the Database, but from then on I keep getting the same error. The only thing I can take from that is that when I save the first document, Mongo looks for the user.email property when I'm creating the new instance of Order and when it doesnt find it, it creates it with a value of null and then the next document would naturally be a duplicate, hence the error. But I'm confused, because this model and router should not absolutely nothing to do with the user ones.

**Here is the error:**[image]

So please if anyone can help me understand why MongoDB is screwing with me or where I'm making a mistake, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Check the indexes on the orders collection. In cli use `db.orders.getIndexes()` or something like that. It looks to me that you might have created an index on `user.email` in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problems was, thanks to Molda: 
At some point I had created these indexes, which I'm still unsure when and how, but I did. Which essentially lead to this error, when I tried to save the second document. 
A simple quick console log of the indexes in the collection showed that I had that index in there.

```js
const indexes = await Order.collection.getIndexes();
console.log(indexes);
```

Then I removed them using this method:

```js
await Order.collection.dropIndexes("user.email_1");
```

And everything worked flawlessly from there.
I hope this helps anyone in this situation in the future and thanks Molda! :)